# Retrieve ALL row data from TWO different months in SAME table?

Tags: mysql, sql

**Re-do Times 2 for clarity**

For simplicity and clarity, the data I am aggregating is in a database I will refer to as "BaseA".

Normally, when comparing Month over month data, I can use the following query:

```
select date_trunc('month',hour) as date,
sum(a) as total_a,
sum(b) as available_b,
sum(c) as c,
sum(d) as net_d
from BaseA where id=12345 and hour >='2022-01-01'
group by date order by date desc
```

Instead of looking back and collecting ALL months from 2021-2022 for the duration I wish to view, I want to collect ONLY two months of data, those being the following:

October 2021
vs.
April 2022

I'd like the data to be visualized in the Month over month format, like so:

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efpjz.png)

However, I would like to:

- Select all BaseA columns (aka, select *)
- Only include Two rows: April 2022 & October 2021

So, should come out like so:
[example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZFAt.png)

This query is what Im trying to do (in word form since I can't write it)

```
Select *
from BaseA
where date 
is in
April 2022
&
October 2022
```

The result of the above should result in 2 rows of data (one for each month referenced)

Is there a place in the below query where DISTINCT would make that actualized?

```
select * from BaseA
where id=12345 and
(
  (month(month) = '04' and year(month) = '2022')
  OR
  (month(month) = '10' and year(month) = '2021')
)
--DISTINCT go where?
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: MySQL or Vertica? As to sample data: Make up some data. Just so we get an idea of what you are dealing with. Keep it simple like three columns date|value1|value2. Show two or three rows for each of the two year/month, and show the expexted result.

Comment: added dummy data in og question and provided ex. of expected/desired output of query

Comment: I believe it's Vertica

Comment: Please make sample date and result match. Your sample data contains 25 rows for one month, the expected result, however, is two rows for two different months. How would we generate these two result rows from the 25 original rows?

Comment: I feel like the sample suffices: the issue is the same for both months. You can see data for the month of April across multiple rows in the first example. The same instance happens for the month of October. Ultimately I'm looking to do the same action that a group by would, but without column restrictions (thus the select *). I would like the end result to be two rows:

October 2021 > data
April 2022 > data

Comment: See previous comment about getting your data to match - but guessing what you are trying to achieve, would SELECT DISTINCT... give you the result you wanted?

Comment: Hmm, it does not. Clearly i'm not doing a great job of explaining...let me update original question with more clarity (hopefully)

Comment: Yet again you've added your example data as links and not as editable data directly in your question

Comment: And yet again the sample data doesn't clarify what you want. Again: Just show three rows for October 2021 and three rows for April 2022 and the expected result. You say now you want two result rows, so the data must get aggregated. What values do you want to show? Minimums, maximums, averages, ...? Show proper sample data in your request. as formatted text.

Comment: Clearly a new user here, y'all. I'll try and figure out how to add a table...not sure it's going to make a difference, it's going to be the same images I attached in table form (which the screenshots are of). BTW Stack makes those images links bc of my profile newness im assuming. So those are the best images we're gettin, folks. I guess, what's not clear about my ask exactly?

Answer (score 0):

To get data for the two months try something like this:

```
select * from BaseA
where _id=12345 and
(
  (month(month) = '04' and year(month) = '2022')
  OR
  (month(month) = '10' and year(month) = '2021')
)
```

I have no idea what you mean by "return data consolidated (grouped) by month (so multiple lines occur per month)". Can you provide dummy data that illustrates the data that you have and the result that you want to achieve?

Comment: For sure - so that month/yr edit worked (thank you!!) Tryin to figure out how to add sample data in a comment..forgive my ignorance...

Comment: Dummy data (only live for 10 min...) https://www.justbeamit.com/bjpq4
More permanent link (just use "slow download option", it's not a lot of data) https://ufile.io/89ardg91

Comment: The dummy data shows multiple rows for same month. I'm trying to combine all monthly data for each month into individual rows (much like date_trunc('month',day) as date + group by date would work. However I can't use group by clause because of the select *.

Comment: Please add your dummy data to your original question - formatted as a table so it is readable. For future reference, you should never link to any data/information

Comment: @CuriousGorged: The dummy data doesn't help me at all understand what you mean by combining/consolidating. Your dummy data shows many rows for one month and that's it. How is this supposed to tell us what you mean? Instead show three rows for one month, three rows for the other and then the desired result rows. And yes, edit your request and place the data there as formatted text.

Comment: Updated dummy data in OG question form along with expected/desired output